# PHP array json_encode adding extra quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following php array, and would like to print it as a clean JSON file, but i'm getting extra quotes around the brackets and comma's. Although the current JSON i get is valid JSON it's not how I want it formatted. See PHP array below, my json_encode output and the preferred json output:

```
    Array
 (
[0] =>             {
[1] =>                 code : "EU27",
[2] =>                 debtA : 967576248244,
[3] =>                 debtB : 6971817122583,
[4] =>                 id : "eur",
[5] =>                 name : "EU",
[6] =>                 popY : 8584663069945,
[7] =>                 popZ : 7565913300548            }
[8] =>             ,
[9] =>             {
[10] =>                 code : "US",
[11] =>                 debtA : 9090198981283,
[12] =>                 debtB : 92189801202,
[13] =>                 id : "usa",
[14] =>                 name : "United States",
[15] =>                 popY : 4514703786570,
[16] =>                 popZ : 774697283542            }
    )
```

Current json_encode output:

```
   [
" {",
" code : \"EU27\",",
" debtA : 1739414366187,",
" debtB : 8719158563660,",
" id : \"eur\",",
" name : \"EU\",",
" popY : 460572909944,",
" popZ : 2396933253407 }",
" ,",
" {",
" code : \"US\",",
" debtA : 7810766144794,",
" debtB : 10536751929567,",
" id : \"usa\",",
" name : \"United States\",",
" popY : 8571487476842,",
" popZ : 1716024078740 }"
    ]
```

Preferred JSON output:

```
   [
 {
  code : "EU27",
  debtA : 1739414366187,
  debtB : 8719158563660,
  id : "eur",
  name : "EU",
  popY : 460572909944,
  popZ : 2396933253407 },
{
  code : "US",
  debtA : 7810766144794,
  debtB : 10536751929567,
  id : "usa",
  name : "United States",
  popY : 8571487476842,
  popZ : 1716024078740 }
   ]
```

I have been searching stackoverflow and found similar problem but can not get it to work. Probably because of my understanding of php and php arrays. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want the properties without quotes? Thats not valid json

Comment: Did you create that array? You should use a 2-dimensional array for this purpose.

Comment: Just implode your array values.

Comment: If the reason why the extra quotes bother you is because you need to transmit the data via HTTP, then I found that my preferred HTTP Library, Guzzle, doesn't need you to JSON-encode the data. Just give it an array, and it will convert it to proper JSON on the wire before making the request.

-- got the tip via #php on Freenode irc.

Answer (score 1):

First of you are making array of improper syntax:

`[0] =>             {`

Secondly the result you are looking for is an array of objects. This said; you will want to do something like the following:

```
$array = array();

$array[0] = new StdObject;
$array[0] -> code = "EU27";
// other values added to object

$array[1] = new StdObject;
$array[1] -> code = "US";
// other values added to second object

$json = json_encode( $array );
```

Alternatively you can also use an array instead of an object:

```
$array = array();

$array[0] = array(
"code" => "EU27",
// other values
);

$array[1] = array(
"code" => "US",
// other values
);

$json = json_encode( $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily.

First Use array in associated form here is how:

```
 $a = [ 
 [
 'code'=>'EU27',
 'debtA' => 967576248244, .... etc
 ], 
 [
 'code'=>'Something',
 'debtA' => 874376347, .... etc
 ]
 ];
```

then cast inner arrays to objects

```
 foreach($a as $k = $v)$a[$k] = (object)$v;
```

then json encode it...
End of tragedy.
Here what I tried as a sample:

```
 $a = [ 
 [
 'code'=>'EU27',
 'debtA' => 967576248244//, .... etc
 ], 
 [
 'code'=>'Something',
 'debtA' => 874376347//, .... etc
 ]
 ];

 foreach($a as $k => $v)$a[$k]=(object)$a[$k];
 echo json_encode($a);
```

And that is what I got:

```
 [{"code":"EU27","debtA":967576248244},{"code":"Something","debtA":874376347}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: JSON will quote the string keys ex: code will be "code". But it will not make a difference in implementation and assignments.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you get is 100% valid and corresponds exactly to the input array you've built. `json_encode()` will never attempt to make the guessing game you take for granted: if you have a string that contains `{` PHP will generate a string that contains `{`—it won't even consider the possibility of starting an object!

You obviously need to build your array this way:

```
$input = array(
    array(
        'code' => 'EU27',
        'debtA' => '1739414366187',
        'debtB' => '8719158563660',
        'id' => 'eur',
        'name' => 'EU',
        'popY' => '460572909944',
        'popZ' => '2396933253407',
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 'US',
        'debtA' => '7810766144794',
        'debtB' => '10536751929567',
        'id' => 'usa',
        'name' => 'United States',
        'popY' => '8571487476842',
        'popZ' => '1716024078740',
    ),
);

$output = json_encode($input);
```

Additionally, key names *must* be quoted—[it isn't an option](http://json.org/) because they are strings:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in
>   double quotes**, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
>   string.

Answer (score 0):

The proper json you want is

```
'             [
                  {
                   "code" : "EU27",
                   "debtA" : "1739414366187",
                   "debtB" : "8719158563660",
                   "id" : "eur",
                   "name" : "EU",
                   "popY" : "460572909944",
                   "popZ" : "2396933253407" },
                 {
                   "code" : "US",
                   "debtA" : "7810766144794",
                   "debtB" : "10536751929567",
                   "id" : "usa",
                   "name" : "United States",
                   "popY" : "8571487476842",
                   "popZ" : "1716024078740" }
                    ]
```

This json corresponds to the multidimenstional array which should be like:
`

```
            Array
              (
                  [0] => Array
                      (
                          [code] => EU27
                          [debtA] => 1739414366187
                          [debtB] => 8719158563660
                          [id] => eur
                          [name] => EU
                          [popY] => 460572909944
                          [popZ] => 2396933253407
                      )

                  [1] => Array
                      (
                          [code] => US
                          [debtA] => 7810766144794
                          [debtB] => 10536751929567
                          [id] => usa
                          [name] => United States
                          [popY] => 8571487476842
                          [popZ] => 1716024078740
                      )

              )`
```

For better understaning see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php         '